# Unable to start Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka

I am setting up Kafka (0.8.2.2) on HDP 2.3 cluster through Ambari. When I try to start the broker, it shuts down with the below error.

```
[2015-12-24 18:37:04,466] FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.clientId(KafkaController.scala:215)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerBrokerRequestBatch.<init>(ControllerChannelManager.scala:189)
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.<init>(PartitionStateMachine.scala:48)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.<init>(KafkaController.scala:156)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:148)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:29)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:72)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Need more information to figure out what is happening. But first you should use Kafka 0.10 at least because there is a lot of change on going on kafka and 0.10 improved/redesigned a lot kafka core.